# How do I decode the multiclass when I use a LabelEncoder for my target variable in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science, multilabel-classification

I have a multi classification problem which I am trying to solve and the target variable contains genders(male, female). I have used a LabelEncoder from sklearn to implement the one hot encoding. I plotted a confusion matrix, and I got an output containing 0's and 1's instead of classes. How would I be able to get back which class was mapped to which binary number(0,1 etc.)? Any suggestions would be very much helpful.

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()

y = encoder.fit_transform(y)

Answer (score 0):

Just use inverse_transform:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data = ['apple', 'orange', 'pinaple', 'orange']
le.fit(data)

encoded = le.transform(data)

>>> [0 1 2 1]

decoded = le.inverse_transform(encoded)

>>> ['apple' 'orange' 'pinaple' 'orange']
```

Also try to read the documentation before asking, there are a lot of examples:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Comment: someone could also say try to search for duplicates before answering, there are a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217005/how-to-reverse-label-encoder-from-sklearn-for-multiple-columns) ;)

Comment: that's exactly what you should do!

Comment: Thanks guys for the help :)